# Existe alguma forma de converter um texto em imagem sem usar o pictureBox no vb6?

Tags: imagem, visual-basic-6, dll, base64, jspdf

### **Introdução**

Possuo uma DLL em VB6 que está gerando uma array de comandos javascript que serão executados em uma pagina asp para gerar um PDF de forma dinâmica. Até ai, tudo certo!
Neste PDF necessito gerar um código de barras, o sistema antigo fazia através de uma fonte que possui os caracteres em código de barra, porem o gerador de PDFs não aceita fontes personalizadas.

### **Solução imaginada**

O gerador de pdf (jspdf) aceita imagens em base64, então pensei em criar uma rotina que gerasse uma imagem do código de barras usando a fonte e então codificasse essa imagem em base64 para ser exibida no PDF

### **Progresso**

1. Consegui criar a rotina para transformar um caminho de imagem (ex: c:\imagem.jpg) em uma string de base64 e funciona corretamente.
2. O gerador de código javascript tambem já funciona corretamente.

### **Dificuldades**

1. Só consigo gerar uma imagem a partir de um pictureBox;
2. Por ser uma DLL não posso criar o pictureBox

### **Duvidas**

1. Existe alguma forma de transformar o texto utilizando a fonte de código de barras sem usar o pictureBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devido ao tempo em que esta pergunta ficou sem resposta, foi necessário solucionar o problema como foi possivel e cabivel no tempo estipulado.

**Solução:**

- A DLL gera o numero do código de barras;
- O asp pega o numero e escreve com a fonte de código de barras em uma div invisivel;
- O javascript após a página carregar pega esta imagem e transforma ela para base64;
- O javascript então utiliza esse código base64 na confecção do PDF;

*Aconselho a aqueles que tiverem um problema parecido, que gerem o pdf no servidor, utilizando algum backend e então disponibilizem para o cliente, é uma das formas que fazemos aqui e é a mais atual(aqui).
Existem diversas formas de se resolver um problema, esta apesar de não ser a indicada e de difícil manutenção foi a solução cabível na época, porem deve ser revisada para evitar futuros problemas.*